# Show less more functionality Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery show less more functionality is not working properly.I did but not showing correctly.Can you find where i did mistake?
JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/WtdEh/273/

```js
var showChar = 14;
var ellipsestext = "";
var moretext = "...";
var lesstext = "Less";
$('span[comments-space]').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  if (content.length > showChar) {
    var show_content = content.substr(0, showChar);
    var hide_content = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
    var html = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" morelink>' + moretext + '</a></span>' + show_content + '<span remaining-content><span>' + hide_content + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html);
  }
});

$("a[morelink]").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
    $(this).removeClass("less");
    $(this).html(moretext);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("less");
    $(this).html(lesstext);
  }
  $(this).parent().next().toggle();
  $(this).next().toggle();
  return false;
});

$("span[remaining-content] span").css('display', 'none');
```

```css
.remaining-content span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Testing<span comments-space>123456783463463463463463469999</span></div>
<div>Testing<span comments-space>123456783463463463463463469999</span></div>
<div>Testing<span comments-space>123456783463463463463463469999</span></div>
```

Comment: what is not working properly and what are you trying to do hide and show what element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you create the 'remaining-content' span, you're thinking that you're amending the html, but you're not, you're adding DOM nodes.

`<span>abc123</span>` needs to become `<span>abc<span class='more'>123</span></span>` and not `<span>123</span><span class='more'>123</span>`.

which changes this line:

```
var html = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" morelink>' + moretext + '</a>'
          +'</span>' + show_content 
          + '<span remaining-content><span>' + hide_content + '</span>';
```

to

```
var html = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" morelink>' + moretext + '</a>' 
         + show_content 
         + '<span remaining-content>' + hide_content + '</span>';
```

then you just need to show/hide `remaining-content` as appropriate

```
if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
    $(this).removeClass("less");
    $(this).html(moretext);
    $(this).parent().find("span[remaining-content]").show();
} else {
    $(this).addClass("less");
    $(this).html(lesstext);
    $(this).parent().find("span[remaining-content]").hide();
}

$("span[remaining-content]").css('display','none');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WtdEh/274/

---

As an aside, you may find it easier to use classes rather than html attributes as random html attributes aren't strictly allowed.  Classes don't need to be related to a style, then can have semantic meaning instead.